# How to style latex enumerate list

Tags: enumerate

I'm trying to create a list like the one below:

[image: Styled List]

I've tried \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{...}, but it's not letting me put in anything beyond symbols and characters (e.g. I can't seem to get a \fbox or \adjustbox working correctly in there).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\adjustbox{cfbox=darkgray 1pt 3pt, bgcolor=darkgray}{\color{white} \theenumi}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\Alph{enumii})}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Which choice...
\begin{enumerate}
\item Answer A
\item Answer B
\item Answer C
\item Answer D
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you put in what you *do* have? (MWE)

Comment: Your MWE doesn't compile.

Comment: I know. It's what I'm trying...

Comment: What I meant was: you need `xcolor`. That is, it doesn't compile really early ! Other than that, it compiles OK for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). I defined a new dedicated list `fancyenum` (I defined it for two nesting levels, but this can be increased if required) producing the desired result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{fancyenum}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[fancyenum,1]{
  leftmargin=12pt,
  labelsep=10pt,
  label={\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \protect\node[overlay,text width=\textwidth,fill=gray!20,anchor=west,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=2em] (bg) {};
    \protect\node[overlay,anchor=west,minimum height=2em,inner sep=0pt,fill=black,align=center,text width=2em,text=white,font=\bfseries] at (bg.west) {\arabic*};
    \protect\node {\rule[5em]{0pt}{0pt}};
    \protect\end{tikzpicture}}
  }
\setlist[fancyenum,2]{label=\Alph*),topsep=0pt,leftmargin=22pt}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{fancyenum}
\item Some test text
  \begin{fancyenum}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \end{fancyenum}
\item Some test text
  \begin{fancyenum}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \end{fancyenum}
\item Some test text
  \begin{fancyenum}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \end{fancyenum}
\end{fancyenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm can't get this to build.
test.tex:20: Use of \\fancyenum doesn't match its definition. [\item]
test.tex:20: Use of \@rule doesn't match its definition. [\item]
test.tex:20: Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@a. [\item]

Comment: @Nelson Which version of `enumitem` and `TikZ` do you have?

Comment: enumitem.sty v3.5.2
tikz v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

Comment: @Nelson In my system (TeX Live2015): 
`enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists` and `pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.15)`. Your PGF/TikZ is outdated. Before thinkinh in updating it, which you should do anyways, let's try a little test first. Open a fresh new document and copy-paste there my example code exactly *as is* (no changes, no modifications). Do you get errors? If so, which ones?

Comment: Same errors. Must be the outdated version...

Comment: @Nelson Seems so. You could try updating it.

Comment: Got it to work. Any ideas on how to make it work with multicol? (two columns) The overlay stretches past the columnsep and extends into the margins. (update: nvm, got it to work with \columnwidth)

Answer (score 1):

A solution which uses only `enumitem`, `eqparbox` ((to keep track of the label width) and `xcolor`. I tried to be as close as possible to the O.P.'s image in his post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{2}

\setlist[myenum, 1]%
{label =\eqparbox[t][\baselineskip]{N}{\colorbox{black}{\,\arabic*\,}} \hskip-0.333em{\color{lightgray!50!} \rule[-0.25\baselineskip]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\eqboxwidth{N}-2\parindent\relax}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+0.4pt\relax} \rule[-3ex]{0pt}{3ex}},
align=left,
font=\bfseries\color{white},
wide=0pt,
leftmargin=\eqboxwidth{N},itemsep =1.5\baselineskip}%

\setlist[myenum, 2]{label=\Alph*),leftmargin=*, topsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}[start=7]%
  \item The main purpose of the first paragraph is to
  \begin{myenum}
    \item describe a culture.
    \item criticize a tradition.
    \item question a suggestion.
    \item analyze a reaction.
  \end{myenum}
  \item As used in line 2, “form” most nearly means
  \begin{myenum}
    \item appearance.
    \item custom.
    \item structure.
    \item nature.
  \end{myenum}
\end{myenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]